# How to access votes count in post show? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

So I have Votes model, that means a votes for posts. My controller have create action, and it works fine, but when i want to take count, i recive nothing.
See the controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @vote = @post.votes.create(votes_params)
    @vote.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def index // here is the problem
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @pro = @post.votes.where(stare: false).count
    @contra = @post.votes.where(stare: false).count
  end

    private

    def votes_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:stare).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Problem is because in index action @post have a nil value... How to repair?

routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :votes
    collection do
        get 'for_vote'
        get 'considered'
        get 'solved'
    end
  end
```

Comment: If `@post` has a value of `nil`, then there apparently is no `post_id` parameter for your index path. Could you post your `routes.rb`?

Comment: resources :posts do
    resources :votes
    collection do
        get 'for_vote'
        get 'considered'
        get 'solved'
    end
  end
-----------------
Here is routes.rb. Maybe the problem is in this: both actions I use in post.html.erb view file... Now I tried this @post.votes.where(stare: false).count just in view file, but it works just once, I need two times.

Comment: A quick fix for that would be to store the result in a variable: `count = @post.votes.where(stare:false).count`, and then store that in `@pro` and `@contra`: `@pro = count` and `@contra = count`.

Comment: Didn't work. The problem is with @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]), it return nil value.

Comment: SOLVED!!!!! I dont need controller to do this, just use in view:
@post.votes.where(stare: false).count - for pro
@post.votes.where(stare: true).count - dor contra